# Mate-power-manager keeps crashing (how to keep it running / automatically restart?)

Tags: crash, mate-desktop

Under Centos 7, `mate-power-manager` (from the EPEL repo) keeps crashing.  When run manually from the command line, at the time of the crash it throws the error:

```
ERROR:gpm-kbd-backlight.c:342:gpm_kbd_backlight_on_dbus_signal: code should not be reached
```

I've found that it's [an incompatibility with `upower`](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/225), and the [workarounds](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/226#issuecomment-322049511) suggested reduce the crashes, but don't eliminate it.

It has been fixed with [version 1.18.1](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/225#issuecomment-341121730)  However, that is not available in EPEL.  I've tried building it myself, but keep getting prompted for sudo with

```
authentication is needed to run mate-power-backlight-helper
```

I really just want `mate-power-manager` to keep running (or automatically restart after a crash) so that I don't miss a critical battery alert.

Comment: Based on https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=259912, editing `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.mate.power.policy` *may* avert the "authentication is needed" prompt in the built-from-source version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of just having the power manager running, the simplest solution seems to be to use `sudo` to edit the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/mate-power-manager.desktop` and uncomment the last line:

```
X-MATE-AutoRestart=true
```

The crashes will still occur, but at least `mate-power-manager` will now automatically restart when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research, it turned out the best long-term thing to do was to re-open the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager/issues/225#issuecomment-447478575) for the [mate-power-manager](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-power-manager) project.  The previously-fixed bug was an outstanding issue in Centos 7 that they fixed pretty quickly once I did that.  Very much appreciated!